# usort() warning although submitting array

Tags: php, sorting, usort

Why doesn't `usort()` sort the array?

```
if ( is_array( $tables ) ) {
    usort( $tables, 'sort' );
} else {
    echo "no array";
}
```

I always get this warning:

> sort() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given

so php thinks its an array but `usort()` not

heres the sort function:

```
function sort( $a, $b ) {
    return strlen( $b ) - strlen( $a );
}
```

Comment: Can you do `var_dump( $tables )` for us real quick?

Comment: How are you able to define a function named "sort" to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the error says `sort() expects`, not `usort() expects`.  That's because PHP is interpreting the callback to `usort` as the built-in [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort) method (which expects the 1st parameter to be an array), not your `sort()` method.

Try renaming your method to something else, like `my_sort`.

```
function my_sort( $a, $b ) {
    return strlen( $b ) - strlen( $a );
}

if ( is_array( $tables ) ) {
    usort( $tables, 'my_sort' );
} else {
    echo "no array";
}
```

Comment: It took a while for me to notice that.